# git clone issue creating modified files

Tags: git

I did a fresh clone from a repo from git using ssh and checked git status in the terminal.
I can see all the files are modified and its asking to add and commit again, but I have not modified anything.

How can I avoid this and what is the correct way to checkout/clone?

Commands:
`gti clone <repo-url>`
`git status`

Comment: The command to clone a repo is: git clone <repo_url>

Can you check the diff and see what you find there?

Comment: Are you by any chance using a case insensitive filesystem? If so, check agains the remote origin if the local files are all lowercase.

Comment: May you update your question with the commands you used?

Comment: @VenkatChaitanyaSama I am not able to see any difference when I check for it. I can see the modified files in the status.

Comment: @NullDev That's not the case bro. Hence thanks for the help.

Comment: @evolutionxbox here we go..

Comment: When you do a git diff, are you seeing message on the console like CRLF changed to LF or something like that?

Comment: @VenkatChaitanyaSama yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your are facing this issue because of line endings.

Try this command:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

and then find ***.gitattributes*** file in your repo and comment out a line like this:

```
* text=auto
```

Finally do a `git checkout` and you should not see the change anymore.

Comment: This temporarily resolves the problem. But what is the permanent solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue with Windows; Windows was changing the [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix)) of all the files(in my case it was changing from 644 to 755)

The solution was to move the project directory from the home directory of the user(e.g. Users/name in Windows 7) to some other directory.

Are you putting the files in your home directory?

Comment: Yes, its in home > proj > <proj-name>. BTW I am using ubuntu 16.04